# pass an array of objects from jquery to php and save to database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi I have been trying to pass an array of objects with geolocation data from jquery to a php script to save to a database.  been up all night trying to get this working so may be missing something small from lack of sleep.

the jquery objects stucture is the following

```
var testData = [];            

        var coords = {
        lat: 12.6544885,
        lng: 23.545665
        };

        var pos = {
         timestamp: 1222355465,
          latlng: coords
            };

            testData.push(pos);


            var coords = {
        lat: 55.6544885,
        lng: 55.545665
        };

        var pos = {
         timestamp: 555,
          latlng: coords
            };

            testData.push(pos);
```

I am trying to post this via .ajax using the following

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(testData),
            //change the url for your project
            url: 'www.mydomain.com/save2.php',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Sucess');
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

and I am decoding at the php side and attempting to place in a database using the following.

```
$myData = json_decode($_REQUEST['testData']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO walk (timestamp, latitude, longitude) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ($myData->timestamp, $myData->latlng->lat, $myData->latlng->lng)";
```

I would appriciate any input on this issue thanks.

Comment: Please run a `print_r($myData)` and post it.

Comment: +1 for value of my data, and also any error messages

Comment: have you tried `$myData = json_decode($_POST['testData'])` ?

Comment: Are you not using [tag:pdo] or [tag:mysqli]? Why insert those variables inside sql string? Use prepared statements.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx I am quote new to jquery and php most of my proggramming experiance is console based.  have to do this for a uni project.  Could you tell me how I can run print_r and get an output as this script does not load the php page in the browser so would have to be reutned to the jquery script somehow thanks

Comment: Well you could create a text file in that directory and put the output there (create the file first): `file_put_contents("textfile.txt",print_r($myData, TRUE))` that will give you the content of the json decoded.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx Hi tanks but the text file I created is not getting data put into it.  I think it must be a bug with my code will look over itand try to get print_r working

Comment: The text file is in the same directory that your php file? The snippet I gave you assumes that

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx yeah its is I thought it may be the jquery not posting however I put alerts after that code to confirm that the post didn't break the script and the alerts fired.

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx ok some success.  i'll explain what i'm try to do basicly making an app with phonegap to track a walk someone does it is stored localy on the device fine but after the user clicks to stop tracking I want to send all the gps data to a sql database via a php script.  I have managed to strip down the position object into single arrays and pass 1 array and use it to update a database.  DO you think it would be a easyier approch to pass 3 separate arrays into the file and do it that way rather than a object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ajax options, try changing `data: JSON.stringify(testData),` to

```
data: { 'testData': JSON.stringify(testData) },
```

otherwise you won't have a valid query string.

Comment: Beat me to it by less than a minute.

Comment: or better yet, get rid of the stringify call altogether.  jquery will automatically convert the object into a query string, encoding it as json is unnecessary.